# Hopping on a lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Usually hopping on a lattice written as
$$H=-tc_i ^{\dagger} c_{i+1} + h.c$$ where $t$ represent hopping amplitude

When we consider hopping on a lattice than, Do we need at least the empty orbitals at each site for hopping to take place or if not than how hopping is possible if all the states are filled?

for example I was introduce to case of hopping of spinless electrons on linear chain where we consider one electron at each site  and take the hopping between nearest neighbours, but how hopping is possible since we have spinless electrons at each site and we have one orbital at each site which is already filled?